# How to view data on crystal report using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, crystal-reports

I have Form.cs on which there is "crystal report viewer" and "button" when i press button the following code is executed. But when i run this code the following error occurs "Application has stopped working". Why?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2012/11/11", "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var data = (from a in dc.GetTable<Voucher>()
               where a.V_Date == dt
               select new { a.V_No }).ToList();

    CrystalReport1 cr = new CrystalReport1();
    cr.Load(@"CrystalReport1.rpt");
    cr.SetDataSource(data);
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
 }
```

Moreover I am using SQL server 2012 and when i created CrystalReport1 I chose "OLE DB >> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL server >> Integrated Security >> Table >> Table field"

Edited:

Using debugger i found error on this line cr.SetDataSource(Data);

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Where exactly does it fail out? Is anything being returned from that select (is data empty)?

Comment: yes data is being returned from sql server. I checked it by displaying it using foreach loop

Comment: what error occurs.. can you show all relevant code..? thanks

Comment: what happens if you were to add this `crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();` aftere the assignment of the `ReportSource`

Comment: @MethodMan there is no other relevant code. When i run the above code the "Application stops working" error occurs.

Comment: so you don't have button click event's or and other code in your cs file.. what method is that code below tied to...?

Comment: are you familiar with how to use the debugger..? please state which line in your code fails..

Comment: where is the .dll located.. did you add it to your references..? what does the `using` section in you class look like..?

Comment: @MethodMan i found the solution. thnx for help

Comment: that's good.. glad that you were able to figure it out.. now you can try to accept your own answer as the acceptable answer... LMB@o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer there was nothing wrong with the code. In App.config file. I replaced this

```
<startup > 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
</startup>
```

with this

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
</startup>
```

and everything is working fine now.
Thanks for help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

In App.config file in your solution explorer just replace this line

```
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
</startup>
```

with this

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
</startup>
```

and it should work.